# Colored logs but NOT based on log level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have multi-thread process that returns logs. I want to have logs from each thread in different color, so i can distinguish that easier. Number of run thread varies from 1 to 8-9. Does anyone have any quick and nice solution?

F.e. i could have smth like this, however I do not know how to add color to log as attr:

```
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

def test_thread_starter(threads_list):
    # ----
    threads = []

```
for _ in threads_list:
    t = ThreadMethodThatDoesLogOnly(log_color)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: https://github.com/alikins/color_debug

Comment: Too bad that documentation is so poor with this one,(Fortunately, author left a lot of comments in code). Thanks for this though :)